# Shorewall: How do I enable ping to a specific IP address where the zone containing that IP has ping disabled

Tags: linux, firewall

I'm using Shorewall.

How do I enable ping to a specific IP address where the zone containing that IP has ping disabled?

Answer (score 0):

in etc/rules....

Suppose you have a zone dmz and in that zone you have the 
external ip address of 67.89.164.199 and the internal ip of 10.0.99.10.

That is the external ip DNAT's to 10.0.99.10

The dmz zone doesn't allow pings from the outside.

Here's what to do:

1)  DNAT    net   dmz:10.0.99.10  icmp      8             - 67.89.164.199
or in other words, send all pings "icmp 8" that come to 67.89.164.199 to 10.0.99.10

2) Ping/ACCEPT net dmz:10.0.99.10
i.e. accept Ping

Answer (score 0):

Allow single ip using

```
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

Reference http://www.trickylinux.net/ping-single-ip-linux/